# Dynamically add fields to relation manager using relationExtendManageWidget()

Tags: field, backend, octobercms

I created a model that have relation with another model. I use the relation manager widget to handle the relation. Everything works great.

Now, I need to dynamically add fields to the relation model depending on the choice of a field in the parent model. I noticed that there is the relationExtendManageWidget() function for that.

However, I don't know how to use it and the documentation doesn't provide any examples. I tried to do that:

```
public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field, $model)
{
    // Make sure the field is the expected one
    if ($field != 'references') return; 

    $widget->addFields([
        'test' => [
            'label' => 'Test',
            'span' => 'left',
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
    ]);

    return $widget;

}
```

But when I go to my form, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function addField() on null
>   /modules/backend/widgets/Form.php line 569

Comment: Just for someone wondered, `relationExtendManageWidget` method is defined in `\Backend\Behaviors\RelationController`, and should be overridden in your controller to use it.

Comment: `relationExtendManageWidget` is not expected to return anything. It'll be just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The `addFields` method does not exist on the $widget object ([Widget Base documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/backend/classes/widgetbase)). To achieve what you want to do, I would recommend extending the form fields instead, using the [extendFormFields](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#extend-form-fields) method, or create a partial instead. An example using the extendFormFields would look like this (code is untested):

```
public function extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context)
{
    if (!$model instanceof MyModel) { //your related model
        return;
    }

    $form->addFields([
        'test' => [
            'label' => 'Test',
            'span' => 'left',
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
    ]);
});
```

Comment: You can't do this for extending the view manager for a relation, this code is only for extending the fields of the main create/update form. For extending the fields of a manage widget the correct method is relationExtendManageWidget, the only problem is that the form is not fully inicialized so you need to bind to the form.extendFields event of the widget

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$widget->addFields(...)`, add the field configurations directly to `$widget->fields`.
This worked for me.

```
public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field, $model)
{
    // Make sure the field is the expected one
    if ( $field != 'references') return;

    $widget->fields += [
        'test' => [
            'label' => 'Test',
            'span' => 'left',
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicitly documented for the manage widget, but it's the same that is explained in the documentation under [Extending the view widget](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#extend-view-widget):

> Since the widget has not completed initializing at this point of the runtime cycle you can't call $widget->removeColumn(). The addColumns() method as described in the ListController documentation will work as expected, but to remove a column we need to listen to the 'list.extendColumns' event within the relationExtendViewWidget() method.

For adding fields we need to listen to the form.extendFields event:

```
public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field, $model)
{
    if ($field != 'references') return; 

    $widget->bindEvent('form.extendFields', function () use($widget) {
        $widget->addFields([
            'test' => [
                'label'   => 'test'
            ],
        ]);
    });        
}
```